# Why does the export of a styled pandas dataframe to Excel not work?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I would like to apply the same background color to cells that have for each PEOPLE instance the name and the related name. I have tried to `df.style.applymap`, it does not return an error but it does not seem to work.  Anyone has any ideas why? Thank you.

```
   clrs = list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys())
   for k in range(len(PEOPLE)):
        if PEOPLE[k].attribute == 'child':
            df1_data = [PEOPLE[k].name, PEOPLE[k].related]
    
            df.style.applymap([lambda x: 'background-color: yellow' if x in df1_data else 'background-color: red'])
    

    df.to_excel('styledz.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: applymap accepts a function, not a list

Comment: also `df.style` is the object, not `df`, so you need to use `df.style.to_excel`. And also you need not create multiple `df.style` instances. Basically there is a lot wrong with your code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i cannot put df.style in a loop, how can i color multiple cells with different colors?

Comment: have you tried reading the user guide for Styling at pandas documentation. it has many examples.

Comment: @ChristinaJ If you find my answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you accept it or upvote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) is some more info on `df.style`. Here I'm using some simple example because I don't have your data available:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10), 'b': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10), 'late': np.random.choice([0, 1], 10).astype(np.bool)})

def highlight_late(s):
    return ['background-color: red' if s['late'] else 'background-color: green' for s_ in s]
df = df.style.apply(highlight_late, axis=1)
df.to_excel('style.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Looks in the excel file like this:

[image]

---

For `cell` based coloring use:

```
def highlight_late(s):
    return ['background-color: red' if s_ else 'background-color: green' for s_ in s]


df = df.style.apply(highlight_late, subset=["late"], axis=1)
```

This gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know how to  color only certain cells with different colors not a whole axis.

Comment: @ChristinaJ I updated the answer to only use one cell for coloring

Comment: Thank u! One last comment, what if i want to color cell a[5] and b[2]. I mean what if they are not in the same column? Lets say a[5] and b[2] have the same string written to it.

Comment: `apply([...], axis=1)` works on the whole row, you can simply check in the function `highlight_late` for a keyword and skip the `subset=["late"]` in the `apply`

Answer (score 0):

Basically your solution will be a modification of the following:

```
df = DataFrame([['mark', 2], ['mike', 4], ['manny', 6]], columns=['name', 'attribute']) 
def style_row(row, people):
    output = Series("", index=row.index)
    if row["name"] in people:
        output['attribute'] = "background-color:red;"
    return output
styler = df.style.apply(style_row, axis=1, people=['mark', 'manny'])
styler
```